# Check value of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"> Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Beer"> Beer<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Wine" checked> Tee

    <span id="check" >check</span>
```

And jQuery:

```
function check()
{
    alert($('input[name=group2]').val());
}
$('#check').click(function(){
    check();
});
$('input[name=group2]').change(function(){
    check()
})
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/j9cj5/

Why this always show me Water? How can i check value of these radio buttons? I would like check this if i change this value and if i click on check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `$('input[name=group2]')` with `$('input[name=group2]:checked')` :)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/j9cj5/2/

The reason this happens is because `$('input[name=group2]')` will generate an array of all your radio buttons and thus will give only the first element (which happens by default). So get the selected element, you must use the `:checked` pseudo selector.

Answer (score 5):

The selector `$('input[name=group2]')` will select all the elements with that name, and `val()` returns only the value for the first element in the collection, so that's always `Water`. You have to target just the checked radio :

```
function check() {
    alert( $('input[name=group2]:checked').val());
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9cj5/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
function check(val) {
     alert(val);
}
$('input[name=group2]').change(function(){
    check($(this).val());
});
```

This is working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j9cj5/1/)